# Changing the Input test data into the dimentional of feature matrix

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, naivebayes

I trained a model with feature matrix dimension (200,716),where 200 is the number of document and 716 is the number of total feature.Now i want to test the model with input test data having feature words (7).How can i mapped this feature to exact same number of feature in which our model get trained,Such that i can use ***model.predict(test_data)*** function for checking the prediction of model on new data.

Comment: You should give more details regarding your question, and maybe an example to help understand the issue. Eg: Are you using some kind of matrix of indicator variables to represent your data? Are the features words in the document?, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will not be too good for you but ... you have to use the same method you used in the first place. there is no general, "magical" way of achieving that, you had your training documents in the raw format and you mapped it to the features by some transformation `f`, and you **have to** store the transformation itself (the function, its dictionary etc.). If you removed it, you cannot do anything. Usually you will save both model (classifier) and preprocessing pipeline (f, your transformation from data to features) in pickle files or any other format of your choice. Then, during prediction time you simply load both parts and apply them again on new data.